# Implementations of Jakarta XML Binding API (formerly JAXB)

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee

[*Jakarta XML Binding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_XML_Binding) is a standard API defined in [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE).

I have found only implementation, [*Eclipse Implementation of JAXB™*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxb-impl). Bundled with [*Glassfish*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) app server, and perhaps others.

Are there any other implementations from which to choose?

Answer (score 0):

## *EclipseLink MOXy*

One I discovered by accident is *EclipseLink MOXy*. See [brochure page](https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/#moxy). This open-source library is part of the [*EclipseLink*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EclipseLink) project, but does work separately as an implementation of the *Jakarta XML Binding* Specification.

I have tried swapping *EclipseLink MOXy* for *Eclipse Implementation of JAXB™* in a simple example app; the swap worked without a problem. Otherwise I no nothing about this product, and have not used it productively.

Find Maven coordinates at a Maven repository such as [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy). For example:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```